# Variables falling out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scope, avaudioplayer

I have a subclass of `AVAudioPlayer` and within that subclass I have a method for stopping the current player and (for reasons I won't explain) manually calling `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` like this:

```
// Handles stopping the player and calling audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
- (void) stopPlayerForTimedRepeat {

    // Stop the player
    [self stop];

    // Manually call the audio player callback
    EditPlayListViewController *playlistController = [[EditPlayListViewController alloc] init];
    [playlistController audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:self successfully:YES];
    [playlistController release];

}
```

However, when I call `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` manually like this, all of my variables in the original `EditPlaylistViewController` fall out of scope.

How do I avoid this so that I still have access to all of my original variables?

Comment: If you're stopping and releasing your player. Naturally, your variables will fall out of scope.

Comment: Yes, but they still fall out of scope even if I stop the player after calling `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a better way to do this without manually calling `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` so that all the variables will still be within scope.

```
// Handles stopping the player and calling audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
- (void) stopPlayerForTimedRepeat {

    // Fast forward the call to the end, which will also call audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
    [self setCurrentTime:[self duration]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable scope loses because you are creating a new object  `EditPlayListViewController *playlistController = [[EditPlayListViewController alloc] init];` in the method after stopping it.

Please declare the player in your `.h` file (like this `EditPlayListViewController *playlistController;` and allocate it in your `viewDidLoad` method (like `playlistController = [[EditPlayListViewController alloc] init];`.

and change your method like this,

```
- (void) stopPlayerForTimedRepeat
{
    // Stop the player
     [self stop];

    // Manually call the audio player callback
    [playlistController audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:self successfully:YES];
    [playlistController release];

}
```

Hope,it'll work for you, if not please tell me.